# Editing the layout of additional product info in sales email?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, layout, xml, email-templates

I have an individual block in **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml**

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
```

**I want to style it's output like so ("PHP" would be floated right):**

[image]

Is this achievable and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on template hints for your store and then do a test order.

Process the order so that you get all of the sales emails. Now open those emails, the red outlines of the blocks and templates will all be in there and you will now know what to edit.

I could have done this for you and told you what to edit, however I don't know the filenames by rote, with template hints enabled I get to find out.

Comment: The path returns app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml , however there's no output elements for additional product info in the script

Comment: Can you not add a column to the items template and use inline styling to fix it to be right aligned? See 'adding images to email templates' questions+answers for ideas on how to go about that.